# Powershell, multi line txt file variables

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I have a text file with hostnames on individual lines:

```
IT4524
IT5135
IT5688
... etc
```

I can import these and list each individual line:

```
$hostname[1]
IT4524
```

I need to pipe each (and all) individual lines through a command. How can I do this without having to write:

```
  If "\\$hostname[1]\c$\test.txt{
      # // File exists
    }Else{
      # // File does not exist
    }

  If "\\$hostname[2]\c$\test.txt{
      # // File exists
    }Else{
      # // File does not exist
    }
```

... ETC

The end result is to check each hostnames C: for a txt file outputted by another PS

Hope I have explained this well enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the host file using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet, iterate over it using [foreach-object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) and check whether the file exists using [Test-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113418):

```
$hostFile = 'c:\hostfile.txt'
get-content $hostFile | foreach {
  if (Test-Path "\\$_\c$\test.txt")
  {
    Write-Host "exists"
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host "doesnt exist"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!